# Is it possible to replace a broken 2..5" 60 gigs data hdd with a 2.5” 160 gigs SATA ssd from a broken Acer Aspire one, ZA3?

Tags: ssd

2.5” 60 gigs SATA hdd of my ThinkPad T60 got broken. Is it possible to replace it with a 2.5” 160 gigs SATA ssd from a broken Acer Aspire one, ZA3?  The ssd appears to be ok and installed lubuntu 16.4 in it. If it is possible, I can save money and retrieve important data from ssd.

Comment: Is there something you believe may not work? 2.5" HDD/SSD are the same shape and size and are essentially interchangeable from a physical and connection standpoint. Some older mainboards may not support SSD, but these are mostly remedied by a BIOS update, and your computer is nowhere near old enough for that to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, to switch a 60 GB HDD for a 160GB SSD.
If possible, you *should* do a complete reinstall of your OS to avoid issues, but otherwise you'll be fine.

Comment: This will certainly go to you. Thank you very much. Accidentally copied and used the word 'answer' instead of your name. ***Sigh**"

Comment: There are products that will transfer an hdd to ssd without reinstall.

Comment: That's true, but they do not always a perfect job.